# False/true changes in console, but doesn't take effect on html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to toggle false/true in an external JS file (with onclick from html).
On button click console displays changes from true to false, but it doesn't take effect on html.
I think the page or its part must be updated (most likely with AJAX) but I am new to it and didn't find how to do it. Please give me a clue.
This is the html:

```
<button id="click" onclick="toggle()">Continuous play</button>
<script src="/players/inlineplayer.js"></script>
<a href="example_1.mp3"></a>
<a href="example_2.mp3"></a>
<a href="example_3.mp3"></a>
    <script src="/players/inlineplayer.js"></script>
```

And this is the part of JS code (I am trying to toggle a boolean in the `playNext: testBool,` string below ):

```
var testBool = false;         
console.log('Default value of bool is',
testBool);
function toggle() {
  testBool = !testBool;    
    console.log('Toggled bool is',
    testBool);                   
}
(function() {
'use strict';
function InlinePlayer() {
  var self = this;
  var pl = this;
  var sm = soundManager;
  var isIE = (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i));
  this.playableClass = 'inline-playable';
  this.excludeClass = 'inline-exclude';
  this.links = [];
  this.sounds = [];
  this.soundsByURL = [];
  this.indexByURL = [];
  this.lastSound = null;
  this.soundCount = 0;
   

  this.config = {
    playNext: testBool, 
    autoPlay: false 
  };
  
  
the rest of JS....}());
```

Comment: Changing the variable `testBool` is not going to change the "playNext" property of that configuration object.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"it doesn't take effect on html"*?  I don't see any code here which updates any HTML.  Can you edit the question to provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the html, now edited.

Comment: `this.config` is set only when `InlinePlayer` is called. Whatever you do to `testBool` after that, does not have any effect on `this.config` ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see for this case **InlinePlayer** is a constructor function that may be creating an instance somewhere. I don't see the end of the code, but my guess is that they are using module pattern in that project.

You can read more about Object constructors here:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp

And also you can learn more about module pattern here:

[https://javascript.plainenglish.io/data-hiding-with-javascript-module-pattern-62b71520bddd?gi=74235fb90acf#:~:text=The%20Module%20Pattern%20is%20one,the%20scope%20of%20the%20function](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/data-hiding-with-javascript-module-pattern-62b71520bddd?gi=74235fb90acf#:%7E:text=The%20Module%20Pattern%20is%20one,the%20scope%20of%20the%20function).

Please notice that since this function is being created within a IIFE, everything declared inside it is out of the scope of the global scope, so you cannot modify the value of that object outside the IIFE.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

My suggestion would be to move the logic of the button inside the constructor function InlinePlayer, so you can handle the value inside it....

```
function InlinePlayer() {
  var self = this;
  .....
  var yourButton = document.getElementById("your-button-id") 
  /* or create it here document.createElement(button) and then append it into the DOM */
  
  .....
  
  this.config = {
    playNext: testBool, 
    autoPlay: false 
  };

  /* maybe you have an init method here or something that initializes the variables in the object instance. 
some other times there is a method that adds all the event listeners....... 
whatever the case may be inside it you would need to attach the event for this button. */

/* otherwise you could create an init function below the variables and you would need to execute it right after its declaration... 
inside it you need to handle the event listener of the button just like this...*/
  .......
  yourButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (self && self.config) {
     self.config.playNext = !self.config.playNext
    }
  });
```

You can read more about events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

don't forget to remove the event subscription when it is not needed...